# Passing values dynamically into a python function chain call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python function:

```
def group_data(filter: str, filter_value: any, db_name: str, single=True, **kwargs) -> any:
   ....
   result = db.users.find({filter: filter_value}, kwargs)

   ...
```

Is it possible to pass the function argument **db_name** into the **result** variable function chain call to replace the **users** dynamically so I can use it for all the **collections** in my mongodb instance?

Example, say I have two collections users, and groups. I want to get the value of **result** like this:

```
 result = db.users.find(...), and 
 result = db.groups.find(...)
```

in the same group_data function by simple passing the arguments of **users**, and **groups**. A sort of chain function call interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def group_data(filter: str, filter_value: any, db_name: str, single=True, **kwargs) -> any:
    ...
    result = getattr(db, db_name).find({filter: filter_value}, kwargs)
    ...
```

You can use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) method to dynamically retrieve attributes
from an object.